# SnakeYaml dump automatically converts numbers(represented as Strings)

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I am using yaml dump method to create a configuration file for my object. I have the following code:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("phonenumber","7285042388");
map.put("name","Cristina");
DumperOptions dumperOptions1 = new DumperOptions();
dumperOptions1.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);
Yaml yaml2 = new Yaml(dumperOptions);
System.out.println(yaml2.dump(map));`
```

Output:

```
phonenumber: '7285042388'

name: Cristina
```

I want the phone number to be shown without single quotes. I've noticed that using a map with Object type for values solves this, but I need the values type to be String. How could I solve this?

Comment: you can use replaceAll method of String class to replace all ' with emply space like replaceAll("'","");

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("phonenumber",  new BigInteger("7285042388"));
map.put("name","Cristina");
DumperOptions dumperOptions1 = new DumperOptions();
dumperOptions1.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);
Yaml yaml2 = new Yaml(dumperOptions1);
System.out.println(yaml2.dump(map));
```

Output:

```
phonenumber: 7285042388
name: Cristina
```